# Laravel giving incompehensible urls leading to "Not found http exception"

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm building a blog with laravel and have edit functionality and resourceful controllers.

Here is the edit method from my controller :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return View::make('posts.edit')->with('post',$post);
}
```

And my edit view :

```
<div class="containeredit">
{{Form::open(['action'=>'PostsController@update'])}}
{{Form::label('Title: ')}}
{{Form::text('title',$post['title'])}}
{{Form::label('Body: ')}}
{{Form::textarea('body',$post['body'])}}
<br>
{{Form::submit('Add Blog Post',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

and at last this is my update controller method

```
    public function update($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $input = Input::all();
    $post->title = $input->title;
    $post->body = $input->body;
    $post->save();
    return "hi";
}
```

But when I click on the edit button , I'm being routed to this url :

```
http://localhost:8000/posts/%7Bposts%7D
```

which leads to a not found error , 
How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a route setup for the form post/put action? Route::put('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@update');

Comment: It's a resource generated by Jeffrey Way's amazing Laravel 4 generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update route expects an id, so you'd change

```
{{Form::open(['action'=>'PostsController@update'])}}
```

to

```
{{Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@update', $post['id']], 'method' => 'put'])}}
```

More info about the routes it creates can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Still getting the same result with {{Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@update', $post['id']]])}}

Comment: If you use resource-controllers your route expects the PUT or PATCH method, check my answer for an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update existing row so you probably want to let laravel know the id of that row :)

```
{{Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'method' => 'patch'])}}
```

Comment: $id doesn't ,for the result of $post['id'] , check the stuff of the bottom

Comment: check edited, post id must be there. Also as @user.. pointed out method must be set to PUT or PATCH